# Simple Breadcrumb Issue

Tags: php

I've been trying to figure out how to make the last item in my breadcrumb have H1 tags in it. Here is a sample code without the H1.

```
// Each tree item has a URL and name. Some may have extra_before and extra_after.
foreach ($context['lateral_navigation'] as $link_num => $tree)
{
    echo '
        <li', ($link_num == count($context['lateral_navigation']) - 1) ? ' class="last"' : '', '>';

    // Show something before the link?
    if (isset($tree['extra_before']))
        echo $tree['extra_before'];

    // Show the link, including a URL if it should have one.
    echo $settings['lateral_navigation_link'] && isset($tree['url']) ? '
            <a href="' . $tree['url'] . '">' . $tree['name'] . '
            </a>' : '' . $tree['name'] . '';

    // Show something after the link...?
    if (isset($tree['extra_after']))
        echo $tree['extra_after'];

    echo '
         </li>';
```

I'm not a PHPer, and I've tried experimenting with it code on this line:

```
 <li', ($link_num == count($context['lateral_navigation']) - 1) ? ' class="last"' : '', '>';
```

Because it shows the "last" only on the last item of the breadcrumb.

I tired this below, but obviously it didn't work:

```
// Each tree item has a URL and name. Some may have extra_before and extra_after.
foreach ($context['lateral_navigation'] as $link_num => $tree)
{
    echo '
        <li', ($link_num == count($context['lateral_navigation']) - 1) ? ' class="last"><h1>' : '', '>';

    // Show something before the link?
    if (isset($tree['extra_before']))
        echo $tree['extra_before'];

    // Show the link, including a URL if it should have one.
    echo $settings['lateral_navigation_link'] && isset($tree['url']) ? '
            <a href="' . $tree['url'] . '">' . $tree['name'] . '
                <div id="arrow">
                  <div class="inside"></div>
                  <div class="border"></div>
               </div>
            </a>' : '' . $tree['name'] . '';

    // Show something after the link...?
    if (isset($tree['extra_after']))
        echo $tree['extra_after'];

    // Don't show a separator for the last one.
    if ($link_num != count($context['lateral_navigation']) - 1)
        echo '';

    echo '
        </h1', ($link_num == count($context['lateral_navigation']) - 1) , '></li>';
}
```

Any help with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$count = count($context['lateral_navigation']); // get count

// Each tree item has a URL and name. Some may have extra_before and extra_after.
foreach ($context['lateral_navigation'] as $link_num => $tree)
{
    $count--; // decrement by 1
    echo ($count == 0) // if zero (last)
        ? '<li class="last"><h1>'
        : '<li>';

    // Show something before the link?
    if (isset($tree['extra_before']))
        echo $tree['extra_before'];

    // Show the link, including a URL if it should have one.
    echo $settings['lateral_navigation_link'] && isset($tree['url']) ? '
            <a href="' . $tree['url'] . '">' . $tree['name'] . '
                <div id="arrow">
                  <div class="inside"></div>
                  <div class="border"></div>
               </div>
            </a>' : '' . $tree['name'] . '';

    // Show something after the link...?
    if (isset($tree['extra_after']))
        echo $tree['extra_after'];

    // Don't show a separator for the last one.
    if ($link_num != count($context['lateral_navigation']) - 1)
        echo '';

    echo ($count == 0) // if zero (last)
        ? '</h1></li>'
        : '</li>';
}
```

Comment: sorry I had initially forgot to put the default `LI` tags. But now will echo them out.